Integral formulation of Shannon's Entropy
I recently noticed that, taking advantage that $I(t) = t\log{t}$ is a primitive of $1+\ln{t}$ and that $I\left(p\right)=\ \int_{p}^{\frac{1}{e}}\left(1+\ln{t}\right)dt+\ \int_{\frac{1}{e}}^{1}{\left(1+\ln{t}\right)dt=\ }\ \int_{\frac{1}{e}}^{1}{\left(1+\ln{t}\right)dt\ -\ }\int_{\frac{1}{e}}^{p}\left(1+\ln{t}\right)dt$, we can rewrite the definition of Shannon's Entropy for a discrete probability distribution as:
$H=\ \sum{\left[\frac{1}{e}-\ \mu\left(p\right)\right]=\ \frac{n}{e}-\ \sum\mu\left(p\right)\ }$, where
$\mu(p)=\int_{\frac{1}{e}}^{p}\left(1+\ln{t}\right)dt > 0$, always
This formulation seems to facilitate certain calculations by making $p$ an extreme of integration.
I would like to ask if someone would know how we can interpret this integral function $\mu(p)$.
Many thanks.

Why is $\mu(p) \gt 0$? Doesn't it depend on whether $p \gt \frac{1}{e}$ or not?

@Srini, no it's always positive, because 1+lnt intercepts the x-axis at 1/e. So, no matter if p> 1/e or p<1/e it's always positive.

Ah, right. Sorry for the distraction.

@Srini, no worries,. It's something subtle that leads to this conclusion. Initially, I also thought that there would be positive and negative terms. That tell us that the Entropy starts at n/e and can only decrease from there.
